# Trying to remove all vowels from a phrase

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am trying to make a program to remove all vowels from a sentence or phrase. I don't get a syntax error, but when I add a word like 'Cool' or anything with more than two vowels next to each other, not all of them get removed. Why is this? 
Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnProcessClick(Sender: TObject);

Var Sentence: string;
K : integer;
Begin
Sentence :=uppercase(edtSentence.text);
For k := 1 to length(sentence) do
 If (sentence[k] in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']) then
begin
Delete(sentence,k,1);
Lbloutput.caption := sentence;
end;
```

Comment: This ends up turning your sentence into all capitals. Why not just convert each letter to uppercase before checking it to the sentence itself doesn't get changed?

Comment: Also there's a problem with your begin...ends. It looks like you're assigning the caption over every time you remove a letter. Move that out of the block and you'll only need to do it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting up when deleting instead of counting down.

Your loop should read :-

`For K := Length(Sentence.Text) DownTo 1 Do`

Comment: Thank you, but why cannot I do it how I presented it?

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger and pay attention to the value of `K` and the character it's pointing to in `Sentence`

Comment: Because when you remove one character, but still increment the loop index variable, you are actually skipping the next character ;) This is really a classic loophole. If you want to remove things from a list, array or the such... you must either do it backwards or you must use a while (instead of a for) loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all characters and remove them in that manner, or you can use StringReplace. The only downside is that you have to use it for every vowel separately, like this.

```
procedure TForm1.btnProcessClick(Sender: TObject);
Var Sentence: string;
Begin
Sentence:=edtSentence.text; //No need to capitalize the string
Sentence:=StringReplace(Sentence, 'a', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
Sentence:=StringReplace(Sentence, 'e', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
Sentence:=StringReplace(Sentence, 'i', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
Sentence:=StringReplace(Sentence, 'o', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
Sentence:=StringReplace(Sentence, 'u', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct alternative solutions.  However, part of your q was "Why is this?"

It's basically because the "for K := [...]" assumes that the length of Sentence is fixed for the duration of the "for" loop, but the action you take in it, calling Delete() changes the length of Sentence, so by doing that, you're pulling the rug from under your own feet.

The way I prefer to think about this coding problem is by analogy with an airport check-in queue.

- You count the number of people in the queue ( "... to Length(Sentence)"; note that with "for ..." this happens once-only, before the loop begins)
- You scan the queue in order starting from the front ("for K := 1 [...]")
- When you get to someone suspicious-looking, you pull them out of the queue ("Delete([...]")
- Everyone behind the pulled person shuffles forward one place (Same with Sentence, when you delete a character).
- But you (incorrectly) resume your scanning on the **next place** in the queue, which is one beyond where the person pulled out was, not with the **next person** after him/her.  So you miss the terrorist who was next in the queue.
- Not only that, but you decided how many people to scan before you started scanning them ("[...] to Length(Sentence)"), but the queue has shortened by the number of people you've pulled out, so eventually you get to the point where you're processing no-longer-occupied places.  If you watch Sentence[K] in the watch window, you'll see that it evaluates to #0 at positions greater than the number of characters deleted so far.

So, whenever your in-loop processing potentially changes the length of the thing you're processing, re-check the length after each change, and check that you resume processing at the correct point.   This, btw, is one of the things While loops were made for.